Chunk produces "Failed to create SQL chunk directory", then runs the 2nd time
I have a notebook that queries our Snowflake instance.  Oddly, the first time I run the SQL chunk it fails with an error, "Failed to create SQL chunk directory".  If I immediately run the chunk again, it will run the query without issue.
Why does this happen?
library(dbplyr)
library(DBI)
db_connection <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
            <connection parameters>
)

The above connection chunk runs fine, first time, every time.  This next chunk is the weirdo:
{sql, connection=db_connection, output.var = "clozd_candidates"}

  SELECT <a bunch of SFDC fields from Snowflake tables>
  FROM <tables> 
  WHERE <clauses>
  GROUP BY <same fields I selected above>

This chunk runs the second time I invoke it, and everytime thereafter for as long as the connection is good.  If I have to reinstate the connection, then I get the error on the first run of the chunk.
What the heck?
I thought I could set this query up in an R Notebook and run the chunks as the full chain, but apparently I have to run them one by one, due to the error.  (Failed to create SQL chunk directory).  Once I've run this chunk the first time, then I'm good.
I was expecting it to run everytime, of course.
Thoughts?
